# Need to click Each li Element without affecting parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have HTML Structure like

```
<ul>
<li><a></a>
<ul>
    <li><a></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a></a>
              <ul>
               <li><a></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add 'active' class for relevant 'a' Element when corresponding li clicked.

Comment: Show us how much you've tried

Comment: `$(this).find('a').addClass('active')`

Comment: could you please explain a bit more. so that we can understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @Rayon, he saying when he click on li only then add "active" class to that relevant "a".

Comment: `$(this).children('a').addClass('active')`

Comment: `$("li > a").addClass("active");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate click handler would most likely solve your problem best.

```
$('ul.master').on('click', 'li', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();

    // I added this line to remove active class from all other a tags
    $(this).parents('ul.master').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhL7od6s/)

You could work on the `<a>` tag directly to capture the click for changing the active class. If you need to work directly with the `<li>` You can attach another handler.

```
$('a').click(function(evt){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('li').click(clickHandler);
```

Comment: Click Event for li needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** method, since you only want to select the direct child

```
$('li').click(function(){
   $(this).children('a').addClass('active')
})
```

or use **[`>`](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)** to select direct child

```
$('li').click(function(){
   $('>a', this).addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: @Neophyte : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#a').on('click', function(){
    $('a', this).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="a"><a></a>
<ul>
    <li id="b"><a></a>
        <ul>
            <li id="c"><a></a>
              <ul>
               <li id="d"><a></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $('a', this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just target the li a directly:

```
$('li a').on('click', function(){
 $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('li').on('click', function(){  
       $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');  
   });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Get first child using  :first (if you have only one anchor per li)  the use addclass method to assign class

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>A</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>C</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a>D</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery + JS code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(){
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
})</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
if($(this).parent('li').length) {
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
}
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!